# Error running embedded server while migrating to Java11

Tags: java, tomcat, cdi, java-11

I'm getting issues while migrating to Java 11 while running Embedded server in my application.

So to migrate from JAVA 1.8 to java 11. I have upgrade to tomcat 9 and checked that my application is working fine with java 1.8 and Tomcat 9.
But when I have switched to Java 11 I'm able to build my Application using Maven but while running embedded server I'm getting below errors.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener]
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.webbeans.corespi.scanner.AbstractMetaDataDiscovery.scan(AbstractMetaDataDiscovery.java:144)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.bootstrapApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:104)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:87)
    at org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(WebBeansConfigurationListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4663)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5131)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:398)
    at com.myApplication.tnt.tools.servers.EmbeddedServer.start(EmbeddedServer.java:133)
    at com.myApplication.tnt.tools.servers.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using tomcat 9.0.14

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.M6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I'm not sure if CDI will cause any issues but I'm using CDI as well in my project.

Updating this issue with the openwebeans dependencies I'm using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-tomcat7</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Some CDI Jars which I'm using in my application are mentioned below :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jcdi_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm not sure if these issues are because of CDI or not but anyone has any information for the CDI jar versions which are compatible with Java 11

Comment: From the stack trace(`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)`), it's mostly because the ASM version underlying in the tomcat dependency is not up to date. You shall seek a Java-11 compatible version of tomcat to resolve that.

Comment: Could you please mention the tomcat version compatible with java 11.

Comment: Well, honestly I am not a tomcat user precisely. Yet the reason I did speculate could be confirmed by looking at the transitive dependencies of the tomcat dependency in your code, specifically for `asm`. If you could share the version in transitive dependencies for that library, you might just be able to predict the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried checking the Transitive dependencies and I found ASM in "openwebbeans" [INFO] +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-impl:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-finder-shaded:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm5-shaded:jar:4.3:compile . So the version is I'm using in My application is 4.3

Comment: Could you try and use *explicit dependency* on `<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
  <artifactId>xbean-asm7-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>` and *exclude the transitive dependency* `org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm5-shaded` , given that asm7 is java 11 compatible, that should at least save you from this error.

Comment: That error got resolved but now I'm getting another error SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/inject/spi/ProcessSyntheticBean Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessSyntheticBean

Comment: I was suspecting it as I made the previous comment. (*at least save you from this error.*)  That's the reason I would suggest waiting or looking more into the tomcat repositories and issues for work going on for its compatibility with Java11.